# How to clone subbranch from android source?

Tags: git, android-source

I am not overly familiar with git. I was trying to download the following branch but I guess this is not the way to do it:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/jb-mr1.1-release
```

What I want is the code from this address https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/jb-mr1.1-release, but I'm not sure what command to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to clone is the files in the branch "jb-mr1.1-release".
So, you cannot put your branch in the end of the git's link to clone the files.
Git allows you to clone the branch by using the following statement:

```
git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>
```

In your case: you should use the following:

```
git clone -b jb-mr1.1-release https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera
```